# Conversion of angle from 360 degree to-90 degree

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Here i am trying to convert angle into +90 degree AND -90 DEGREE FORMAT.For  desired elevation angle i got answer properly.How to converert angle -90deg to zero, zero to +90 degree format. you can find after 12pm angle suddenly changes to 360 degree. I wnated to calculate only azimuth . Desired_elevation and Desired_azimuth should be in same angle format

```
DATE    Hour    min sec TS  mode    Desire_elevation    Desire_AZIMUTH  Azimuth altitude
14/7/2014   0   15  11  911 INIT    0   0   6.61    -55.31
14/7/2014   0   30  11  1811    INIT    0   0   6.67    -54.94
14/7/2014   0   45  11  2711    STOW    0   0   12.59   -54.33
14/7/2014   1   0   11  3611    STOW    0   0   17.9    -53.43
14/7/2014   1   15  11  4511    STOW    0   0   23.25   -52.15
14/7/2014   1   30  11  5411    STOW    0   0   28.22   -50.56
14/7/2014   1   45  11  6311    STOW    0   0   32.77   -48.71
14/7/2014   2   0   11  7211    STOW    0   0   36.92   -46.62
14/7/2014   2   15  11  8111    STOW    0   0   40.66   -44.33
14/7/2014   2   30  11  9011    STOW    0   0   44.04   -41.87
14/7/2014   2   45  11  9911    STOW    0   0   47.08   -39.27
14/7/2014   3   0   11  10811   STOW    0   0   49.82   -36.53
14/7/2014   3   15  11  11711   STOW    0   0   52.28   -33.69
14/7/2014   3   30  11  12611   STOW    0   0   54.51   -30.76
14/7/2014   3   45  11  13511   STOW    0   0   56.52   -27.75
14/7/2014   4   0   11  14411   STOW    0   0   58.34   -24.67
14/7/2014   4   15  11  15311   STOW    0   0   59.98   -21.54
14/7/2014   4   30  11  16211   STOW    0   0   61.48   -18.35
14/7/2014   4   45  11  17111   STOW    0   0   62.85   -15.12
14/7/2014   5   0   11  18011   STOW    0   0   64.09   -11.85
14/7/2014   5   15  11  18911   TRACK   70  90  65.22   -8.55
14/7/2014   5   30  11  19811   TRACK   70  90  66.25   -5.22
14/7/2014   5   45  11  20711   TRACK   70  90  67.19   -1.87
14/7/2014   6   0   11  21611   TRACK   70  90  68.05   1.51
14/7/2014   6   15  11  22511   TRACK   -70 68.05   68.82   4.9
14/7/2014   6   30  11  23411   TRACK   -70 68.82   69.52   8.32
14/7/2014   6   45  11  24311   TRACK   -70 69.52   70.15   11.75
14/7/2014   7   0   11  25211   TRACK   -70 70.15   70.71   15.19
14/7/2014   7   15  11  26111   TRACK   -70 70.71   71.19   18.64
14/7/2014   7   30  11  27011   TRACK   -70 71.19   71.61   22.1
14/7/2014   7   45  11  27911   TRACK   -67.9   71.61   71.96   25.57
14/7/2014   8   0   11  28811   TRACK   -64.43  71.96   72.23   29.05
14/7/2014   8   15  11  29711   TRACK   -60.95  72.23   72.42   32.53
14/7/2014   8   30  11  30611   TRACK   -57.47  72.42   72.52   36.01
14/7/2014   8   45  11  31511   TRACK   -53.99  72.52   72.52   39.49
14/7/2014   9   0   11  32411   TRACK   -50.51  72.52   72.41   42.98
14/7/2014   9   15  11  33311   TRACK   -47.02  72.41   72.16   46.46
14/7/2014   9   30  11  34211   TRACK   -43.54  72.16   71.74   49.93
14/7/2014   9   45  11  35111   TRACK   -40.07  71.74   71.12   53.39
14/7/2014   10  0   11  36011   TRACK   -36.61  71.12   70.24   56.84
14/7/2014   10  15  11  36911   TRACK   -33.16  70.24   69.01   60.26
14/7/2014   10  30  11  37811   TRACK   -29.74  69.01   67.31   63.66
14/7/2014   10  45  11  38711   TRACK   -26.34  67.31   64.95   67
14/7/2014   11  0   11  39611   TRACK   -23 64.95   61.6    70.26
14/7/2014   11  15  11  40511   TRACK   -19.74  61.6    56.75   73.4
14/7/2014   11  30  11  41411   TRACK   -16.6   56.75   49.48   76.33
14/7/2014   11  45  11  42311   TRACK   -13.67  49.48   38.34   78.88
14/7/2014   12  0   11  43211   TRACK   -11.12  38.34   21.51   80.73
14/7/2014   12  15  11  44111   TRACK   9.27    90  359.35  81.4
14/7/2014   12  30  11  45011   TRACK   8.6 0.65    337.38  80.65
14/7/2014   12  45  11  45911   TRACK   9.35    22.62   320.89  78.76
14/7/2014   13  0   11  46811   TRACK   11.24   39.11   309.99  76.18
14/7/2014   13  15  11  47711   TRACK   13.82   50.01   302.89  73.24
14/7/2014   13  30  11  48611   TRACK   16.76   57.11   298.14  70.09
14/7/2014   13  45  11  49511   TRACK   19.91   61.86   294.85  66.82
14/7/2014   14  0   11  50411   TRACK   23.18   65.15   292.53  63.47
14/7/2014   14  15  11  51311   TRACK   26.53   67.47   290.86  60.08
14/7/2014   14  30  11  52211   TRACK   29.92   69.14   289.65  56.65
14/7/2014   14  45  11  53111   TRACK   33.35   70.35   288.78  53.2
14/7/2014   15  0   11  54011   TRACK   36.8    71.22   288.18  49.74
14/7/2014   15  15  11  54911   TRACK   40.26   71.82   287.77  46.26
14/7/2014   15  30  11  55811   TRACK   43.74   72.23   287.53  42.78
14/7/2014   15  45  11  56711   TRACK   47.22   72.47   287.42  39.3
14/7/2014   16  0   11  57611   TRACK   50.7    72.58   287.42  35.81
14/7/2014   16  15  11  58511   TRACK   54.19   72.58   287.53  32.33
14/7/2014   16  30  11  59411   TRACK   57.67   72.47   287.72  28.85
14/7/2014   16  45  11  60311   TRACK   61.15   72.28   288 25.37
14/7/2014   17  0   11  61211   TRACK   64.63   72  288.34  21.9
14/7/2014   17  15  11  62111   TRACK   68.1    71.66   288.76  18.44
14/7/2014   17  30  11  63011   TRACK   70  71.24   289.25  14.99
14/7/2014   17  45  11  63911   TRACK   70  70.75   289.81  11.54
14/7/2014   18  0   11  64811   TRACK   70  70.19   290.44  8.11
14/7/2014   18  15  11  65711   TRACK   70  69.56   291.14  4.7
14/7/2014   18  30  11  66611   TRACK   70  68.86   291.92  1.3
14/7/2014   18  45  11  67511   TRACK   70  68.08   292.78  -2.08
14/7/2014   19  0   11  68411   TRACK   70  67.22   293.72  -5.44
14/7/2014   19  15  11  69311   TRACK   70  66.28   294.75  -8.77
14/7/2014   19  30  11  70211   TRACK   70  65.25   295.89  -12.07
14/7/2014   19  45  11  71111   TRACK   70  64.11   297.13  -15.34
14/7/2014   20  0   11  72011   TRACK   70  62.87   298.5   -18.57
14/7/2014   20  15  11  72911   STOW    0   0   300 -21.76
14/7/2014   20  30  11  73811   STOW    0   0   301.66  -24.89
14/7/2014   20  45  11  74711   STOW    0   0   303.48  -27.97
14/7/2014   21  0   11  75611   STOW    0   0   305.5   -30.98
14/7/2014   21  15  11  76511   STOW    0   0   307.73  -33.92
14/7/2014   21  30  11  77411   STOW    0   0   310.21  -36.76
14/7/2014   21  45  11  78311   STOW    0   0   312.96  -39.49
14/7/2014   22  0   11  79211   STOW    0   0   316.02  -42.1
14/7/2014   22  15  11  80111   STOW    0   0   319.42  -44.56
14/7/2014   22  30  11  81011   STOW    0   0   323.19  -46.84
14/7/2014   22  45  11  81911   STOW    0   0   327.36  -48.93
```

Answer (score 1):

Azimuths are defined on a full $360°$ range, that can be $-180°..+180°$ or $0°..360°.$ (Elevations are on a $180°$ range, $-90°..+90°$.)

Whatever convention you take, you cannot avoid a $360°$ jump somewhere when doing a full turn.

To enforce the convention $A..A+360°$, use

```
while x        < A -> x' = x + 360°
while x - 360° > A -> x' = x - 360°
```

Comment: Depending on the initial range of $x$, the `while`'s can be replaced by `if`'s or even avoided, but this requires greater care.

Comment: azimuth ranges are given in table. I converted elevation angle from -90 degree to +90 degree subtracting 90 from existing elevation/altitude

Comment: Depending on how your elevations were computed/provided to you, subtracting 90° can be right or wrong. And forget about restricting the azimuth to the range -90°..+90°, this is wrong.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust i am coverting it to inclinometer angle

Comment: You provide no information on ranges.